# R studio seems to be passing too many arguments to the "as.yaml" function when creating r markdown script

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Using R , R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03), RStudio, Version 1.0.136, on Windows 7 (64-bit) I am having trouble creating a new R markdown script from RStudios interface. I get the following error:

```
Error in .Call("as.yaml", x, line.sep, indent, omap, column.major, unicode,  : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (8), expecting 7 for 'as.yaml'
```

The following code was produced in the new script:

````
---
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

The header information seems to be missing. I recently updated Rstudio and never had this issue on previous versions.

I have updated all my R packages and still get the error.

sessionInfo gives the following:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.15.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.0 yaml_2.1.14
```

Any help and insight will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What version of R?

Comment: R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)

Comment: What does `sessionInfo()` return?

Comment: Added the info in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what function is ultimately calling `as.yaml`, but in the latest version of the `yaml` package (which you are using), an additional argument [was added](https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/commit/01c5521a47245a454401d9e235354cab20112ac1) to this function.

Comment: That makes sense.